# OWL-S semantic services creation and execution

Tags: web-services, semantics, semantic-web, owl, service-discovery

I'm trying to improve the semantic web services' discovery to satisfy better the user. For that, I choose to use OWL-S. So I created an ontology using Protégé then I generated semantic web services using OWL-S editor within Eclipse (these services have been in part generated automatically since they are already developed in Java). What I can't do now is the execution of these services: I don't know how to proceed. I need your help please, I didn't find good documentation or tutorials about the life cycle of OWL-S services. Could you please help me and suggest me some useful tools, tutorials..?

PS: do you think that OWL-S is still used or do you suggest something else? What is the most common way to develop semantic web services nowadays?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OWl-S is a W3C consortium standard, therefore documentation is available regarding that. Check the below links

http://www.w3.org/Submission/OWL-S/

http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/

http://www.ai.sri.com/daml/services/owl-s/examples.html

Comment: Thank you, I have already checked these links (before asking my question) but I'm still stick with service execution, I do not know how to execute an OWL-S service and what specific tool to use because some of the documentation isn't available anymore... That's why I'm trying to have comments and suggestions from experimented people around here.